# Set cookie after fetch request response from auth server

Tags: express, authentication, cookies, fetch

I just started learnign about the express library, im developing an app that access restricted info about a user using an Eve Online API, to do this the user is redirected to an authentication page to get an access and refresh token.

Everything works fine until I try to pull the 'refresh_token' from the response and set a cookie with it.

The error:

`(node:20600) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: res.cookie is not a function`

My code:

```
const url = 'https://login.eveonline.com/v2/oauth/token';
const options = {
    'method':'POST',
    headers:
    {
        'authorization':'Basic '+ process.env.ENV_PASS,
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'host':'login.eveonline.com'
    },
    body:''
}

function send_get_request(req, res){
    options.body =`grant_type=authorization_code&code=${req.query.code}`
    fetch(url,options,{credentials:'include'})
    .then(handle_stream)
    .then(handle_json)
    .then(set_cookie)
    .then(redirect_home)
}

function handle_stream(res){
    return res.json() //handless data stream, returns responce
}
function handle_json(res){
    return res.refresh_token
}
function set_cookie(res){
    return res.cookie('refresh_token','hello')
}
function redirect_home(res){
    res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/home')
}
router.get('/',send_get_request)
```

I tried breaking the .then() block but still res.cookie doesn't exits. Also tried using credentials but it doesn't work.

Comment: You seem to confuse the two variables `res` in your code: One stands for the response that your middleware sends back to the client, the other stands for the response you are _receiving_ from the `fetch` operation.

Comment: I see, I guess I need to set a cookie with the res outside the fetch()?

Comment: But how do I get the data from the fetch response and add it somewhere outside fetch()? Do I create a variable and store that value in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains *two* variables `res`: One stands for the response that your middleware sends back to the client, the other stands for the response you are receiving from the fetch operation. Only the `handle_stream` function operates on the latter, whereas `set_cookie` and `redirect_home` operate on the former.

The last three function are also synchronous and need not be chained with `.then`. The are invoked synchronously in a function that takes as parameter the `json` which `handle_stream` produces asynchronously.

```js
function send_get_request(req, res){
  options.body =`grant_type=authorization_code&code=${req.query.code}`;
  fetch(url,options,{credentials:'include'})
  .then(handle_stream)
  .then(function(json) {
    var refresh_token = handle_json(json);
    set_cookie(res, refresh_token);
    redirect_home(res);
  });
}
```

It is all perhaps easier to understand with the `async-await` syntax:

```
async function send_get_request(req, res){
  options.body =`grant_type=authorization_code&code=${req.query.code}`;
  var response = await fetch(url,options,{credentials:'include'});
  var json = await handle_stream(response);
  var refresh_token = handle_json(json);
  set_cookie(res, refresh_token);
  redirect_home(res);
}
```

Comment: I figured that the problem here was in the response from fetch can't set cookies, I was struggling to figure out how I obtain the response from fetch and set a cookie with the middleware, it seems that I don't understand how sync and async functions work very well yet, thank you for the answer I will try implementing this